# How to access files within my bundle?

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I have a simple question, but don't seem to see the answer in a previous thread, so here goes.

I want to access image files within my bundle, and the paste this string into html in various UIWebViews.

The code below seems to return a garbage string. It does not return nil, so I assume my found.

```
NSString *imageString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myimage" ofType:@"png"];
```

Am I accessing this file correctly?

Comment: That is the correct way to find an file within your bundle. How are you examining the string? What is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inserting the string into your HTML, remember it should be a URL and not a path to a file. You may be able to simply add "file://" to the front, or you could use a NSURL object as follows:

```
NSString* urlString = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imageString] absolutePath];
```

Then inject `urlString` into your HTML instead.